# C : can not stop the for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

i have a problem that the for loop just keep going , when i debug it said that after n=4 ,i=4 it automically assign i = 1  againt . i dont know what wrong with that , please help (coding c with dev c++)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[4][4] , sum = 0;

    for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)
    {
        printf ("enter row %d : ", n+1);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)
            scanf ("%d",&a[n][i]);
    }
    printf ("row totals : ");
    for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)
        {
            sum += a[n][i];
            printf ("%d",sum);
        }
        sum = 0 ;
        printf ("%d ",sum);
    }
    printf ("\ncolumn total : ");
    for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)
            sum += a[i][n];
        sum = 0 ;
        printf ("%d ",sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Which* `for` loop? You have six.

Comment: No aparrent debugging, DCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `int a[4][4]` but you iterate loop out of bound in index.

```
for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)
```

According your initialization, a indexes will be

```
a[0][0], a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3]
a[1][0], a[1][1],a[1][2],a[1][3]
a[2][0], a[2][1],a[2][2],a[2][3]
a[3][0], a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3]
```

You feel that from `a's` last index 3. So when you for loop `for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)`iterate, `n will be 0,1,2,3,4` and `i will be 0,1,2,3,4` where `4x4` is out of index in `a` and

So, your need to change initialization `int a[5][5]`

You can try like:

```
int a[5][5] , sum = 0;

    for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)
    {
        printf ("enter row %d : ", n+1);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)
            scanf ("%d",&a[n][i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You access index out of bound , and writing at that index causes *undefined behaviour* .

```
  int a[4][4] , sum = 0;           
 for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)          //goes out of bounds
 {
     printf ("enter row %d : ", n+1);
     for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)      // goes out of bound
        scanf ("%d",&a[n][i]);           
 }
```

Loop goes from `0 to 4`(*5 elements in rows and cloumns*) but `a` is a 2-d matrix of `4X4` elements therefore , valid indexes are `0 to 3` for both rows and cloumns . Similar with all loops.

**1.** Either chane loop condition to `i<4` for all loops

**OR**

**2.**  second way declare `a` as -

```
int a[5][5];            // matrix of 5X5 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array declared as

```
int a[4][4];
```

The valid indices to access the elements of the array are `a[0][0]` - `a[3][3]`.

You are using memory out of bounds while reading the data.

```
for (int n = 0 ; n <= 4 ; ++n)  // that needs be n < 4
{
    printf ("enter row %d : ", n+1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i)  // That needs to be i < 4
        scanf ("%d",&a[n][i]);
}
```

As a consequence, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Fix similar errors in the other `for` loops too.

Answer (score 0):

The array index starts from zero.So 4 elements is 0,1,2,3 .Your loop should start with 0,and end when it reaches 4,so it should be like:

`for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++n )`

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled your code and it is successfully executed.

It returns following output :

enter row 1 : enter row 2 : enter row 3 : enter row 4 : enter row 5 : row totals : -1217042128-1217042128-1217042128185799622718579962260 -1-12200988131854791911634862970-5823832860 -12172462561860502616186050261719950161267777694700 -121724665618604554321994974368212948856221294885630 1-107438404321461990619275694299275694290 
column total : 0 0 0 0 0

[click here](https://www.codechef.com/ide) and paste your code to compile online.